# Materialize datepicker is not opening inside a modal

Tags: javascript, css, datepicker, materialize

In my webpage I have a button to trigger a modal. Inside that modal there is a input field for date. If I click the datepicker it is supposed to be opened.

However, the code is not working if the input date field is inside a modal. For testing purpose I brought it outside and then it is working perfectly.

My code is below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn modal-trigger"  href="#testModal">Open Modal</button>
        <div id="testModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
            <input type="text" name="testDate1" class="datepicker">
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="testDate2" class="datepicker">
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
        var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems,{});
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

There are two input field. One is named 'testDate1' which is inside the modal. Another one is named 'testDate2' which is outside. The outside one is working. Not the inside one.

How can I use datetime modal inside another modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `datepicker` inside modal is getting loaded, but do not have `height`. Set the height to `100%`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
    var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems,{});
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems);
});
```

```css
#testModal .modal {
      height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <button class="btn modal-trigger"  href="#testModal">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="testModal" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
        <input type="text" name="testDate1" class="datepicker">
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="testDate2" class="datepicker">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
container: "body"
```

to the options, when initializing the materialize modal and it will open inside the body, not inside the modal!

Answer (score 1):

Jquery add line ' container: "body" '

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        container: "body", // carregar dentro do MODAL ------------------------
        default: 'now', //hora atual
        fromnow: 0, // padrão para o milesegundos
        twelvehour: false, // AM/PM = false | 24h = true
        format: "HH:ii:SS",
        donetext: 'ok', // btn OK
        cleartext: 'limpar', // bnt clear
        canceltext: 'cancelar', // btn cancel
        autoclose: false, // fechar automatico
        ampmclickable: true, // AM PM clicavel
        vibrate: true
    });
});
```